# Vue served over nginx returns index for all assets, but only on deeplink

Tags: vue.js, nginx

i know similar questions have been asked a thousand times, but none seems to fit exactly to my problem.

i have a vue (cli3) prod build deployed to a server running nginx.

the recommended `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html` works, **but** only if i open /

if i navigate from / to /dashboard, everything still works.

if i then refresh (and open /dashboard directly), index.html is returned for all assets, js, css, everything (and therefore says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for vendors.js and app.js)

(vue-router is set to history more)

what can i do to solve this? something has to be wrong... do i have to change anything else? anything on vue side? i'd appreciate any help :)

## edit:

i tried adding `/$uri /$uri/` to nginx config, to force loading assets from /, but that didn't work either :/

if you need any additional info on my configs, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

the (surprisingly simple) solution was:

i had my vue publicPath set to

`publicPath: ('./'),` (which means: assets are resolved relatively, so on /dashboard, it would look for /dashboard/app.js, which is obviously stupid)

after change to

`publicPath: ('/'),`, it works as expected.

sorry for wasting everyone's time, maybe someone someday will be saved a bit of headache with this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have run the Vue Js application directly using Application path like for example root /var/www/path/of/Vuejs; I would recommend you to run the Vue Js application Using Pm2 start or npm serve and use Nginx reverse proxy of your application port. like your VueJs application is running 8080. below is the Nginx redirection code for the reference.

```
 server {

listen 80;

listen [::]:80;

server_name xyz.com;

location / {

    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}  }
```

Comment: it's the prod build, so not "running" it at all. it's just index.html and a bunch of .js files...

Comment: you can test the Vue Js application running with NPM and pm2 on staging server